# docker-compose - Application can't communicate with postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, scrapy, docker-compose

I have a `scrapy` application which I'm trying to containerized it. Basically, this is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  scrapper:
    container_name: scrapper
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    volumes:
      - ./scrapper/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

And this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

But when I try to execute my application using the following command: `docker run -it scrapper_scrapper scrapy crawl angeloni`, I'm receiving this message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 88, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

Why this is happening? When I execute `docker-compose ps` command, it shows:

```
  Name                Command              State            Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
postgres   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
scrapper   python3                         Exit 0
```

Comment: can you try to remove that `links`?

Comment: @Federkun it continues with same message

Comment: try to use `postgres` when connecting from scrapper, instead of `db`

Comment: @Federkun still the same

Comment: wait, are you getting the error when you run `docker run` manually?

Comment: @Federkun, exactly

Comment: then you need to specify the network where postgres is. `docker networks ls` to list them and then `docker run --network your_network_name ...`

Comment: @Federkun, thank you so much! Post as answer, so I can give to you the credits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `docker-compose up` to start `db`, that container will run under its network that is also created by docker compose. As such, running `docker run ...` will not be able to connect to that instance, since it is not running on the same network. But you can specify it with:

```
docker run --network $network_name
```

To get the docker networks available, you can run:

```
docker networks ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to explicitly define a user network and put your containers on it:

- https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Under the section:

> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.